# difficulties with lm.fit(): 'C_Cdqrls' not found

Tags: r

i'm trying to reproduce what the lm.fit function 
is doing. But i have a problem where it calls the 
'C_Cdqrls' routine:

```
n<-100
p<-5
x<-cbind(1,matrix(rnorm(n*(p-1)),n,p-1))
res<-rnorm(n)
y<-x%*%bet+res
tol<-1e-07
z<-.Call(C_Cdqrls, x, y,tol)
```

i get:

```
Error: object 'C_Cdqrls' not found
```

using 'C_Cdqrls' instead yields:

```
the Error in .Call("C_Cdqrls", x, y, tol) : 
  C symbol name "C_Cdqrls" not in load table
```

In the same vein, summary.lm() calls a function called 
qr.lm on a lm-object but doing :

```
qr.lm(lm(y~x-1))
```

yields:

```
Error: could not find function "qr.lm"
```

my question is: how to get both .Call(C_Cdqrls, x, y,tol) and 
qr.lm() to give the same results as they do when called by 
lm.fit() and summary.lm() respectively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`C_Cdqrls` is an unexported object in the namespace of the `stats` package. To see it, use `stats:::C_Cdqrls`.